# Hyperledger peer not in docker swarm after service update

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, docker-swarm

I have a Hyperledger Fabric network running with Docker swarm. I want to test Fabric by taking some peers down and see if the network still functions.

When the network is running I stop/start a peer container. Then I use the 'docker service update $peer-service --force' command to see if it goes back to being a service. Docker then makes a different new container and adds it to the service.

The new container has not joined the channel and has no chaincode installed on it. The first container still exist but is not part of the swarm anymore. I think it will be very inconvenient to manually install everything on a peer when it goes down on an already running network with many chainscodes.

Is there a way to join the old peer container back as the same service to the swarm?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use volumes so that the block/channel data persists. So map the directory in the peer container that contains this information to a directory on your host machine.

Comment: I am using that, that's not the problem. I can reach all the files I need. The problem is everything on the new containers has to be joined/installed again because it is a newly created container that is used as the updated service. I want to use the old one that is still floating around with everything installed on it.

Comment: Even when you exec into the container (both the old and the new?) you have access to the data, or you just have it on your host? The containers themselves need to have it, and that's all that's needed to be considered part of a channel (it's just files), so I'm guessing after the service update these containers no longer have the data? Is everything else about the new service identical to the old (including placement in the swarm)?

Comment: Every peer has access to the genesis.block, channel.tx and mychannel.block in the peer/channel-artifacts folder. When I update my peer1.org1 service, the new container still has access to the same files but is not part of the channel and no chaincode is installed. When I use "peer channel join -b mychannel.block"  the peer is newly joined to the channel and the same thing with installing chaincode. What do you mean with placement in the swarm? The service does have a slightly different name. E.g. old peer1-r2r82ru vs new peer0-swrg48g3u

Comment: Also, with docker without swarm this problem does not happen, because when you take a peer down and up again, the exact same peer (with everything installed) is used. With swarm mode it just makes a fresh copy of a new container that has access to data but nothing is installed.